# why creating a new Thread to do I/O in onCreate() still causes error?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Part of my code as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final NetDataHandler handler = new NetDataHandler();
    marketList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    marketList.setAdapter(adapter);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HTTPUtils.getJsonData(HTTPUtils.TARGET_URL, handler);
        }
    }).run();
```

These code will only be running when I turn off the Strict Mode.I have read the document about using the **AsyncTask** to avoid this.It says I shouldn't do I/O operation in **main thread**, but I think I have created a new thread.
My problem is, isn't this **new Thread()** a different thread comparing to the **main thread**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `.start()` instead of `.run()`